Reactive RabbitMQ, metrics for ACK, NACK (requeue = false) and NACK (requeue = true)?
How can I track the metrics of number of ACK, NACK (requeue = false) and NACK (requeue = true) messages if I have configured a RabbitMQ reactive client with manual ack?
I have configured my application with the Spring Boot and I have added a bean
    @Bean
    MetricsCollector metricsCollector(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        return new MicrometerMetricsCollector(meterRegistry);
    }

I have verified that I get metrics for CONNECTIONS, CHANNELS, CONSUMED_MESSAGES, ACKNOWLEDGED_MESSAGES and REJECTED_MESSAGES, which is expected since my application is consuming messages. To my understanding, the REJECTED_MESSAGES consists of both NACK (requeue = false) and NACK (requeue = true)? Is there a way to distinguish them?
Please find a meta implementation of my application logic below:
    /**
     * Subscribes to a RabbitMQ queue and processes messages such that:
     * - ACKs messages if processing was successful
     * - NACKs messages with {@code requeue = true} if processing failed
     * - NACKs messages with {@code requeue = false} if an exception occurred during processing
     */
    void process() {
        Receiver receiver = RabbitFlux.createReceiver();

        receiver.consumeManualAck("some_queue").doOnNext(acknowledgeableDelivery -> {
            byte[] body = acknowledgeableDelivery.getBody();
            try {
                boolean processSucceeded = doSomethingValuable(body);
                if (processSucceeded) {
                    acknowledgeableDelivery.ack();
                } else {
                    acknowledgeableDelivery.nack(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                acknowledgeableDelivery.nack(false);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Do something valuable with the message body
     * @param body the RabbitMQ message body
     * @return {@code true} if the processing was successful, {@code false} otherwise
     * @throws Exception if an error occurs during processing
     */
    boolean doSomethingValuable(byte[] body) throws Exception {
        // do something valuable
    }

